# Composite tangent function questions (domain and solving an equation)

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, rational-functions

The question is as follows:

> Let $h$ be the function such that $h(x) = \tan\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{x+2}}\right)$. (a) Find the domain of $h$ and (b) find the values of $x$ such that $h(x)=1$.

For part a, I notice that $1/(x+2)$ is the argument of a square root function. My class defaults to functions having a domain and codomain of real numbers, so it follows that $1/(x+2)$ must be nonnegative. By interval testing, I determine that $x \in   (-2,\infty)$.

I also notice that tangent has undefined values, i.e. the undefined values of $\tan(x)$ are $x \in \pi/2 + \pi n, n \in \mathbb{Z}$. So this must also be considered in the domain: $$\sqrt{\frac{1}{x+2}} \ne \frac{\pi}{2} + \pi n, n \in \mathbb{Z}$$

If I square both sides and then isolate $x$, it results in $$ x \ne \dfrac{1}{\left(\frac{\pi}{2} + \pi n\right)^2} -2,\ n\in\mathbb{Z}$$

So the domain of $h$ is $$\left\{x \mid x\in\mathbb{R}, x\in (-2,\infty), x \ne \frac{1}{(\pi/2+\pi n)^2}-2, n \in\mathbb{Z} \right\} $$ Is this answer and set-builder notation okay?

For part b, solving $ \tan\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{x+2}}\right) = 1$ lead me to $$ \sqrt{\frac{1}{x+2}} = \frac{\pi}{4} + \pi n,\ n\in\mathbb{Z}$$ and squaring both sides and solving for $x$ gives $$ x = \frac{1}{\left(\frac{\pi}{4} + \pi n\right)^2} - 2,\ n\in\mathbb{Z}$$

This seems to hold for $n\ge 0$, but for negative $n$, this results in a wrong result (leading to $h$ giving values of $-1$ instead of $1$). How could I have predicted an extra restriction for $n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\displaystyle\sqrt{\frac{1}{x+2}} = \frac{\pi}{4} + \pi n,\ n\in\mathbb{N}$ because you should only consider natural number values of n (including 0), otherwise you are equating a square root to a negative number, and you're only looking at real domains/codomains.

Comment: Would this also be necessary for finding the domain in part (a) when solving $\sqrt{\frac{1}{x+2}} \ne \frac{\pi}{2} + \pi n, n \in \mathbb{Z}$? It seems interesting that for part (a), the negative values of $n$ still work out in terms of getting an undefined tangent

Comment: The negative values of $n$ also result in undefined $h(x)$ because they are outside the domain of $\sqrt \frac {1}{x+2}$. Take for example, $n = -1$. Your statement says $ \sqrt \frac {1}{x+2} \neq - \frac {\pi}{2}$, which is redundant given the fact that you're looking at real domain only. This isn't unique to negative integers. Take for example $n = -1.6$ (although not in $\mathbb{Z}$), which also causes $h(x)$ to be undefined. However, positive values of $n$ correspond to where $h(x)$ "blows up".

Comment: Just realized what you really meant. The reason that negative values of $n$ in the expression $x \neq \frac{1}{\left(\frac{\pi}{4} + \pi n\right)^2} - 2,\ n\in\mathbb{Z}$ also give an undefined tangent is because for every negative $n$, you can find a positive $n$ that gives the same value. For example, $n=-1$ is the same as $n=0$. $n=-2$ is the same as $n=1$. In other words, the negative $n$ are an exact copy of the positive $n$.